# SQL COUNT & GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
---ID----NAME----INVITED_BY---
   1      A         
   2      B          1
   3      C          1
   4      D          2
```

all I want is to get the result:

```
---ID----NAME------INVITES---------
   1      A          2 (COUNT OF INVITED_BY)
   2      B          1
   3      C          0
   4      D          0
```

Comment: I want to get the result of COUNT(invited_by) grouped by user...

Comment: I don't understand how you get your results, the example data that you showed us, doesn't seem to correlate with your desired ouptut.

Comment: why not try using count and group by as stated in the question? Might be easier to do the actual "invited by"-calculation outside sql though.

Comment: @Lamak, B and C are invited by A.. and D is invited by B.. I want to extract the COUNT of invited users

Answer (score 4):

You could do a self join to count the number of persons invited:

```
select  yt.id
,       yt.name
,       count(distinct inv_by.id) as invites
from    YourTable yt
left join    
        YourTable inv_by
on      yt.id = inv_by.invited_by
group by
        yt.id
,       yt.name
```